# How can I get element from XML file with attribute having specific value

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing

XML file:

```
<Node name="node1">
   <Node name="node2">
      <Node name="node3">
         <Node name="node4">
           ...
         </Node>
      </Node>
   </Node>
</Node>
```

How to select or get "Node" object with "name" attribute having value as "node3" (or any specific value)?

Currently I am using xml.etree.ElementTree

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

document = ElementTree.parse( 'filename.xml' )
nodes = document.find( 'Node')
for node in nodes:
    if node.attribute('name') == "node3":
        print("found")
        break
```

Is there better way to **avoid for loop**? I am fine with other XML parser modules as well.

I am using `python 2.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) you can use XPath:

```
In [1]: from lxml.etree import parse

In [2]: tree = parse('nodes.xml')

In [3]: tree.xpath('//Node[@name="node3"]')
Out[3]: [<Element Node at 0x180ec30>]
```

With multiple predicates:

```
In [4]: tree.xpath('//Node[@name="node3"][@value="value3"]')
Out[4]: [<Element Node at 0x155d1e0>]
```

Comment: Can I add more than one attributes also to this like [@name="node3" @value="value3"]?