# i want to write python file out put to xls or xlxs file

Tags: python

I want to write username and output (taksh) in xls file. i want to do it for 1000 to 5000 users. i am new to Python and work as PBX engineer.

my code and out put is below:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# this statement performs a GET on the specified url
response = requests.get('https://10.10.10.10:8443/cucm-uds/users?last=XXXXXX',verify=False, auth=('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX'))


# print the json that is returned

print (response.text)

print('**********************')

#doc= print (response.text)

root = ET.fromstring(response.text)


for child in root:
     doc=print(child.tag)

for user in root.findall('user'):
    name=user.find('userName').text

print(name)
```

output of file:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 821
    InsecureRequestWarning)
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
Devices = 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users uri="https://10.10.10.10:8443/cucm-uds/users" version="10.5.2" start="0" requestedCount="64" returnedCount="1" totalCount="1">
    <user uri="https://10.10.10.10:8443/cucm-uds/user/taksh">
        <id>d96a9ee4-1992-4a37-b6dd-6c0702792e08</id>
        <userName>taksh</userName>
        <firstName>taksh</firstName>
        <lastName>XXXXXX</lastName>
        <middleName></middleName>
        <nickName></nickName>
        <phoneNumber>11111</phoneNumber>
        <homeNumber></homeNumber>
        <mobileNumber>+1-111-111-1111</mobileNumber>
    </user>
</users>



user

userName

taksh
```

Comment: sorry output was not clear:

Answer (score 1):

you could check python pandas library

you dataframe will looks something simillar to this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( data={ "user":data1,"name":data2} )
```

where data1,data2 are the list containing the result after parsing.
create a data frame by parsing the file .

```
>>> writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()
```

which will get you the excel sheet

for parsing a xml documnet please go through this link

[xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141939/how-can-i-get-element-from-xml-file-with-attribute-having-specific-value)

Comment: I tried below function. It is not working.
df3 = pd.DataFrame( data={ "USERNAME":df1,"FIRSTNAME":df2 })



df1 and df2 are dataframes as mentioned below:

susername = pd.Series(userName, index=['0'])
df1= pd.DataFrame(susername,columns=['USERNAME'])

sfirstName = pd.Series(firstName, index=['0'])
df2= pd.DataFrame(sfirstName, columns=['FIRSTNAME'])




as you mentioned above function is not working. I want to print about in below format in xls sheet.

USERNAME FIRSTNAME
Taksh1   taksh